# What is the default YUV format supported by libjpeg for encoding?

Tags: linux, libjpeg

I want to understand that what is the default format supported by libjpeg for encoding...The enum says JCS_YCbCr what does it mean ?

Is it YUV420SP, YUV420P or YUV422P

Answer (score 1):

With some experiment i found out that libjpeg by default uses YUV-444-interlaced-packed format for encoding.